# Looking inside an object for a specific string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, json

On JavaScript, I have the following JSON:

```
var mJSON = {
    "monster":[
        {"id":"150","name":"Richard"},
        {"id":"100","name":"Gregory"},
        {"id":"200","name":"Rachel"},
        {"id":"250","name":"Mike"}
    ]
}
```

I need to refine this object by a string inputted by the user. For example: "100".
The result should be a new JSON like this:

```
var zJSON = {
    "monster":[
        {"id":"100","name":"Gregory"}
    ]
}
```

I tried looking in Google on easy ways to run through a JavaScript object searching for a string, but without success. There's nothing like jQuery's `$.inArray` too, as far I know. Anyone has any idea?
I'm thinking about converting this JSON into a string, grep it for the value inputted by the user, and then converting the string to JSON again, but I think this will be too troublesome for something that could be easy to achieve.

Comment: That is not a "JSON object", it's an object literal. JSON is a text format for representing data.

Comment: You're actually right. Thanks for pointing it out. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map)?

```
var id = 100;
var result = $.map(monsters, function(monster){
    return monster.id == id ? monster : null;
});
```

JQuery.map() applies function to each argument of the array (`monsters`) and produces the new array that contains the values returned by the function. What is important in this case is that if function returns `null` then the element is removed from the resulting array.

**EDIT:**
As @Jan has kindly suggested in his comment [$.grep](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep) suits even better! Here is the code example for your monsters:

```
var id = 100;
var result = $.grep(monsters, function(monster){
    return monster.id == id;
});
```

Comment: A +1 for the link (and example) However this *poorly named construct* should be called `flatMap` as that mirrors the semantics better.

Comment: Don't use jquery.map. Use jquery.grep!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just loop through the array removing stuff that doesn't match?

Answer (score 1):

Without using libraries, you could do something like this:

```
var mJSON = {
    "monster":[
        {"id":"150","name":"Richard"},
        {"id":"100","name":"Gregory"},
        {"id":"200","name":"Rachel"},
        {"id":"250","name":"Mike"}
    ]
};

var searchTerm = "100";

var result = mJSON.monster.filter(function(e){
    // if you want loose(r) searches, you could use a regex here
    // rather than explicit equality
    if(e.id == searchTerm)
    {
        return true;
    }
});
console.log(result);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbrecht/MZQzM/

Comment: +1 However this will not work in standard ECMAScript ed3. `filter` was added with ECMAScript 5th Edition (some browsers may have had support for a longer time), so this needs to be taken into account when developing.

Comment: Good to know.. didn't actually check which spec this was introduced in :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var mJSON = {
    "monster":[
        {"id":"150","name":"Richard"},
        {"id":"100","name":"Gregory"},
        {"id":"200","name":"Rachel"},
        {"id":"250","name":"Mike"}
    ]
};
var searhKey = "100";

var found = false, i = 0, pos = -1, l = MJSON.monster.length;
while(!found && i < l) {
    if(MJSON.monster[i].id == searchKey) {
        pos = i;
        found = true;
    } 
    i += 1;
}
if(found) {  
    alert(pos);
} else {
    alert("not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `grep` method. Example:

```
var obj = {
  monster: [
    { id: "150", name: "Richard" },
    { id: "100", name: "Gregory" },
    { id: "200", name: "Rachel" },
    { id: "250", name: "Mike" }
  ]
};

var input = "100";

var filtered = {
  monster: $.grep(obj.monster, function(e){
    return e.id == input;
  })
};
```